# wirelessHD using with FPGA

Tags: rf, fpga, wireless, digital-communications, transceiver

I going to make a system to transfer data between 2 FPGAs wirelessly with high rate.
I found that wirelessHD method can do this, now what is the required hardware to establish such system?

Comment: How many bits per second do you plan on using? Are you planning to use full duplex or half? Are you using any kind of error detection and correction codes? Will the wireless connection have to work through walls or are you fine that it will work in clear sight? What's the distance you're planning to use them at? I can go on to narrow your problem further. But I shouldn't have to, you should extend your question by editing it and filling in your further requirements. Otherwise you will get an extremely vague answer because your question is very vague. We want numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[WirelessHD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WirelessHD) is a proprietary standard, which means that you'll have to buy chips from the consortium members (or modules based on those chips) and interface them to your FPGA according to the datasheet.